# Оставить консоль открытой при traceback python

Tags: python, консоль

У меня код, где множество проверок на возможные ошибки. После чего я упаковываю его pyinstaller в exe.

Как сделать так, что бы при ошибки консоль не закрывалась, а показывала саму ошибку?

Comment: Варианты: 1 - добавьте отлов исключений на самом верхнем уровне (условно - код у вас вызывается через какую-то функцию, оберните в try-catch вызов этой функции), после вывода traceback добавьте пустой input(), чтобы программа закрывалась не сразу после ошибки 2 - Сделайте логирование ошибок в файл через модуль logging или https://github.com/Delgan/loguru

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    1/0 
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    input()
```

обычный пример, в блоке try могут быть ваши действия, которые проверяются на ошибки